# How to format / view data from Firebase as a table row using Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm just a beginner using Flutter, and I want to show data from Firestore in an Horizontal Data table. This is the code I wrote, but it doesn't show any data, and there is no error in the terminal!

I don't know where the problem is.

The collection is named patients and every doc from this collection there is a name , image , date of birth and gender:

```
class _BackgroundState extends State<Background>{
CollectionReference _collectionRef =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('patients');
  final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  dynamic alldata;
Future<dynamic> getData() async {
        QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _collectionRef.get(); 
    final allData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();

 }
@override
  void initState() {
super.initState();
    getData();
  }
List<Widget> _getTitleWidget() {
    return [
      _getTitleItemWidget('#', 30),
      _getTitleItemWidget('Name', 100),
      _getTitleItemWidget('Gender', 100),
      _getTitleItemWidget('Date of Birth', 200),
    ];
  }
   Widget _getTitleItemWidget(String label, double width) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(label, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
     
    );
  }
   Widget _generateFirstColumnRow(BuildContext context, int index) {
   return Container(   child: new Text(alldata['name']) , 
      
  }
   Widget _generateRightHandSideColumnRow(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: new Text(alldata['name']),
          
        ),
         Container(
          child: new Text(alldata['genre']),
          
        ),
         Container(
          child: new Text(alldata['birth']),
          
        ),
      ],
    );
   }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
   return  Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only( top: 100,),
                 child: HorizontalDataTable(
                   leftHandSideColumnWidth: 50,
                   rightHandSideColumnWidth: 500,
                   isFixedHeader: true,
                   headerWidgets: _getTitleWidget(),
                   leftSideItemBuilder: _generateFirstColumnRow,
                   rightSideItemBuilder: _generateRightHandSideColumnRow,
                   rowSeparatorWidget: const Divider(
                   color: Colors.black54,
                   height: 1.0,
                   thickness: 0.0,), ), ); }}
```

Comment: Are you following any Firebase documentation to come up with the code provided? Have you tried connecting to the Postman API? Did you try connecting to Flutter using these [steps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios)?

Comment: I don't use any APi . For the connection with firebase , i'm included it depending on some response in stackoverflow , not the same case but the same objectif